# How shall I understand "." in filename expansion?

Tags: bash

In Bash's Manual, for filename expansion:

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character `.` at
>   the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be
>   matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.
>
> When matching a filename, the slash character must always be matched
>   explicitly.
>
> In other cases, the `.` character is not treated specially.

Can you give some examples to explain the cases in the quote?

How shall I distinguish the usage of `.` in filename expansion from its unrelated usage of hardlink `.`?

Comment: The information you cite is basically explaining how filenames starting with `.` (e. g. `.ssh` or `.bashrc`) are hidden from display by default, and accordingly not matched in globs by default (i. e. `ls *` does not show dotfiles, including `.` and `..`.).  `.` is not expanded, as it is not a glob, it is an explicit reference to the hardlink to the current directory.  It happens to also start with `.`, and so is not included by default in globs such as `*`.

Comment: Thanks. What does "unless the shell option dotglob is set" mean? What do the last two sentences in the quote mean?

Comment: The shell option `dotglob` allows for hidden files to be matched with a glob such as `*`.  The sentence about slashes means that by default you will not descend into subdirectories, which are denoted by `/`.  The last sentence means that a `.` in the middle of a filename (e. g. `filename.txt`) is to be treated just like any other character (which is why `filename.txt` in the current directory will  appear in the output of `ls *`).

Answer (score 5):

There is no *usage* of `.` in filename expansion. If you use filename expansion, filenames which start with `.` are usually excluded, unless you explicitly asked for those, using something like `.*` or `.?`. `/` is not a valid character in a filename, so `*` doesn't match `/`.

```
$ touch foo .foo; echo *; echo .*; echo ./*; echo; ./.*
foo
.foo
./foo
./.foo
```

Note how `*` and `./*` excluded `.foo` - yet the first `echo` command had no usage of `.`, and the third `echo` command used `./`, so the wildcard is separated from the `.` by a `/`. To match filenames starting with `.`, you must explicitly specify the leading `.` - `.*`, `./.*`. However, in this case the role of `.` is no different from, say, the role of `a` in `a*`.

This exception can be disabled by using `shopt -s dotglob`.

Since there is no special usage of `.` in filename expansion, there is nothing to distinguish. The only special characters in filename expansion are `*`, `?`, `[...]`.